# How do you perform a join to a table with "OR" conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, inner-join

I have a SQL statement that I can't seem to solve for... I'm not sure how to perform an "OR" on my join. In fact, I'm not sure if I should even be doing a join at all... Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT o.* FROM dbo.Orders o
    INNER JOIN dbo.Transactions t1 ON t1.OrderId = o.OrderId
                                  AND t1.Code = 'TX33'
    INNER JOIN dbo.Transactions t2 ON t2.OrderId = o.OrderId
                                  AND t2.Code = 'TX34'
WHERE o.PurchaseDate NOT NULL
```

I haven't ran this yet, but I assume that this will get me all orders that have a purchase date that also have BOTH TX33 and TX34 transactions. Any orders without both of those transactions won't show up (due to the INNER JOINs). The part I'm stuck at is this:

I need to be able to also ensure that the order also contains either:

- TX35 AND TX36
- TX37
- TX38 AND TX39

Only one of those additional conditions is necessary. I know I can't simply INNER JOIN because that means it's required to be there. If I do a regular JOIN I could possibly make it work if one of the 'OR' conditions wasn't itself an 'AND' condition (I'm not sure how to do `TX35 AND TX36` as one JOIN condition, nor `TX38 AND TX39`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM dbo.Orders o
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t1 
               WHERE t1.OrderId = o.OrderId   AND t1.Code = 'TX33'
             )
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t2 
               WHERE t2.OrderId = o.OrderId   AND t2.Code = 'TX34'
             )
  AND
    (     EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t1 
                   WHERE t1.OrderId = o.OrderId   AND t1.Code = 'TX35'
                 )
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t2 
                   WHERE t2.OrderId = o.OrderId   AND t2.Code = 'TX36'

    OR  EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t 
                 WHERE t.OrderId = o.OrderId    AND t.Code = 'TX37'
               )

    OR    EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t1 
                   WHERE t1.OrderId = o.OrderId   AND t1.Code = 'TX38'
                 )
      AND EXISTS ( SELECT *   FROM dbo.Transactions t2 
                   WHERE t2.OrderId = o.OrderId   AND t2.Code = 'TX39'
                 )
    ) ;
```

---

You could also write it like this:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM dbo.Orders o
  JOIN
    ( SELECT OrderId
      FROM dbo.Transactions
      WHERE Code IN ('TX33', 'TX34', 'TX35', 'TX36', 'TX37', 'TX38', 'TX39')
      GROUP BY OrderId
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Code = 'TX33' THEN Code END) = 1
         AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Code = 'TX34' THEN Code END) = 1
         AND ( COUNT(DISTINCT 
                     CASE WHEN Code IN ('TX35', 'TX36') THEN Code END) = 2
            OR COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Code = 'TX37' THEN Code END) = 1
            OR COUNT(DISTINCT 
                     CASE WHEN Code IN ('TX38', 'TX39') THEN Code END) = 2
             ) 
    ) t
    ON t.OrderId = o.OrderId ;
```

Comment: I think this is definitely the best approach. No exponentially increasing lookups whatsoever.

Comment: @Martin: Thnx. You should note however that most DBMS (and certainly SQL-Server) has several (combinations of) options for choosing a plan and executing a query, depending on the available indices and table statistics. I think you are assuming that only **["Nested Loop Join" algorithm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191426(v=sql.105).aspx)** is available.

Comment: The second query doesn't appear to require pairing of TX35/TX36 or TX38/TX39, just the presence of one.  In fact, if all of the choices were listed in one `IN` it would have the same effect.

Comment: The second query is based on the assumption that a `Code` cannot repeat for a given `OrderId`, e.g. two or more TX35s will not occur for one order.

Comment: @HABO: No, it's not based on that assumption. That's why I have the `DISTINCT` inside the `COUNT()` function.

Comment: @ypercube - My apologies, I didn't catch the `DISTINCT`.  That'll do it.

Answer (score 3):

The selection logic needs to be in the `WHERE` clause.  Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT o.* FROM dbo.Orders AS o, dbo.Transactions AS t1, dbo.Transactions AS t2
WHERE t1.OrderId = o.OrderId AND t2.OrderId = o.OrderId
AND o.PurchaseDate NOT NULL
AND (
  (t1.Code = 'TX33' AND t2.Code = 'TX34') OR 
  (t1.Code = 'TX35' AND t2.Code = 'TX36') OR 
  (t1.Code = 'TX37') OR 
  (t1.Code = 'TX38' AND t2.Code = 'TX39') 
)
```

In the case where you need four independent selection criteria, you will need to `JOIN` the table four times, for example:

```
SELECT o.* FROM dbo.Orders AS o, dbo.Transactions AS t1, dbo.Transactions AS t2
WHERE t1.OrderId = o.OrderId AND t2.OrderId = o.OrderId 
AND t3.OrderId = o.OrderId AND t4.OrderId = o.OrderId
AND o.PurchaseDate NOT NULL
AND (t1.Code = 'TX33' AND t2.Code = 'TX34')
AND ( 
  (t3.Code = 'TX35' AND t4.Code = 'TX36') OR 
  (t3.Code = 'TX37') OR 
  (t3.Code = 'TX38' AND t4.Code = 'TX39') 
)
```

Comment: So I need at least 4 selections on Transaction since TX33 AND TX34 are required and the 3rd/4th selection (t3, t4) are to check for TX35/TX36 OR TX37 OR TX38/TX39?

Comment: Yes, you will need to `JOIN` the table as many times as you need independent transaction variables.

Comment: This is not equivalent to what the OP wants. It will return duplicate results.

Answer (score 2):

You can have complex condition in an `ON` clause.  Using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` allows you to handle the odd case (TX37) in the `WHERE` clause.

Note that references to `R` in the `WHERE` clause must handle NULLs to avoid converting the outer join to an inner join.

```
select L.*
  from dbo.Orders as L left outer join
    dbo.Orders as R on R.OrderId = L.OrderId and (
      ( L.Code = 'TX33' and R.Code = 'TX34' ) or
      ( L.Code = 'TX35' and R.Code = 'TX36' ) or
      ( L.Code = 'TX38' and R.Code = 'TX39' ) )
  where L.PurchaseDate is not NULL and ( L.Code = 'TX37' or R.Code is not NULL )
```

If you really want only orders that contain TX33, TX34 **and** one or more of the other patterns then it is a little more complicated.  Using `group by L.OrderId` with a `count( L.OrderId )` lets you find orders that have, say, two or more matches among the patterns.  It begins to approach something like this:

```
declare @Orders as Table ( Id Int Identity, OrderId Int, Code VarChar(4), PurchaseDate Date )
insert into @Orders ( OrderId, Code, PurchaseDate ) values
  ( 1, 'TX37', GetDate() ),
  ( 2, 'TX37', GetDate() ), ( 2, 'FOO', GetDate() ),
  ( 3, 'TX33', GetDate() ), ( 3, 'TX34', GetDate() ),
  ( 4, 'TX33', GetDate() ), ( 4, 'TX34', GetDate() ), ( 4, 'TX37', GetDate() ),
  ( 5, 'TX33', GetDate() ), ( 5, 'TX34', GetDate() ), ( 5, 'TX35', GetDate() ),
    ( 5, 'TX36', GetDate() ),
  ( 6, 'TX33', GetDate() ), ( 6, 'TX34', GetDate() ), ( 6, 'TX35', GetDate() ),
    ( 6, 'TX36', GetDate() ), ( 6, 'TX37', GetDate() ),
  ( 7, 'TX38', GetDate() ), ( 7, 'TX39', GetDate() ), ( 7, 'TX35', GetDate() ),
    ( 7, 'TX36', GetDate() ), ( 7, 'TX37', GetDate() )

select * from (
  select L.OrderId,
    Max( case when L.Code = 'TX33' and R.Code = 'TX34' then 1 else 0 end ) as Mandatory,
    Count( L.OrderId ) as Matches
    from @Orders as L left outer join
      @Orders as R on R.OrderId = L.OrderId and (
        ( L.Code = 'TX33' and R.Code = 'TX34' ) or
        ( L.Code = 'TX35' and R.Code = 'TX36' ) or
        ( L.Code = 'TX38' and R.Code = 'TX39' ) )
    where L.PurchaseDate is not NULL and ( L.Code = 'TX37' or R.Code is not NULL )
    group by L.OrderId ) as Arnold
  where Mandatory = 1 and Matches > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

After fiddling with it for a while, I think I have achieved your goal with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT o.*, t3.Code as t3 FROM dbo.Orders o
        INNER JOIN dbo.Transactions t1 ON t1.OrderId = o.OrderId
                                      AND t1.Code = 'TX33'
        INNER JOIN dbo.Transactions t2 ON t2.OrderId = o.OrderId
                                      AND t2.Code = 'TX34'
        INNER JOIN dbo.Transactions t3 ON t3.OrderId = o.OrderId
                                      AND (
                                           t3.Code = 'TX35' OR 
                                           t3.Code = 'TX37' OR
                                           t3.Code = 'TX38'
                                          )
    ) WHERE t3 = 'TX37'
        OR (t3 = 'TX36' AND EXISTS (SELECT t.Code FROM dbo.Transactions t WHERE t.OrderId = o.OrderId AND t.Code = 'TX36'))
        OR (t3 = 'TX38' AND EXISTS (SELECT t.Code FROM dbo.Transactions t WHERE t.OrderId = o.OrderId AND t.Code = 'TX39'))
```

The inner `SELECT` should return only Orders linked to Transactions with codes TX34, TX35, and either TX35, TX37 or TX38. We keep a copy of this last code in the results.

Then we have to further narrow down the list, by keeping Orders whose 3rd code was either TX37 (no further conditions needed) or orders which have the remaining code associated to them.

I think this approach should perform better than joining in the Transactions table four times without filtering it first: it should require `O*(T+T+T)*(T+T) = 6*O*T^2` iterations, whereas the four-unfiltered-joins approach would require `O*T*T*T*T = O*T^4` iterations.

Comment: This is just a re-write of OP's query, it doesn't meet the requirements set out for the query.

Comment: It doesn't even do that. The OPs query atleast made sure the order had both TX33 and TX34. This will select the order if it has only 1 of them.